# When refreshing collectionView, it crashes because it doesnt update the numberOfItemsInSection

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, uicollectionview

I have refresh method when user pulls down and it seems like it doesn't update the array count and just crashes:

**Here is the crash:**

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 9 beyond bounds [0 .. 8]'
```

**Here is my code:**

Query Data: (used to refresh as well)

```
- (void) queryData
{
    PFObject *queryPhotos = self.userInformationObject;
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Photo"];
    [query whereKey:@"userTookPhoto" equalTo:queryPhotos];
    [query orderByAscending:@"createdAt"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray * _Nullable objects, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (!error) {
            imageFilesArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];
            [self.myCollectionView reloadData];

            [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
        }
    }];
}
```

**CellForItemAtIndexPath**

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString * const reuseIdentifier = @"imageCell";
    imageCollectionCell *cell = [self.myCollectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    // Configure the cell



    cell.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 0.5;
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 7.0f;
    cell.clipsToBounds = YES;


    PFObject *imageObject = [imageFilesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    PFFile *imageFile = [imageObject objectForKey:@"image"];
    [imageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (!error) {

            cell.imageViewCell.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"Fail");
        }
    } progressBlock:^(int percentDone) {

    }];
    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    //#warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    //#warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of items
    return [imageFilesArray count];
}
```

This is all the code relating to the refresh, and showing the cells, I dont know whats going wrong, hope someone has an answer.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think code is fine

Comment: try to call [self.refreshControl endRefreshing]; before [self.myCollectionView reloadData]; in queryData Method and Log your imageFilesArray count value is correct on not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code.

```
- (void) queryData
{

   [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];

    PFObject *queryPhotos = self.userInformationObject;
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Photo"];
    [query whereKey:@"userTookPhoto" equalTo:queryPhotos];
    [query orderByAscending:@"createdAt"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray * _Nullable objects, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (!error) {
            imageFilesArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];
        }
    }];
    [self.myCollectionView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: quick question, sometimes when i go to the collectionview, sometimes it shows up blank, till i pull to refresh. Wondering why this happens.

Comment: the reloadData statement needs to be inside the query completion block, and should be run on the main thread since the completion block will return on an async thread.